# Youtube API Analytics - How to get subscribers demographics not viewers

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I have the info about getting the viewers' demographics for youtube channel [From [here]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query), but can I get the same data for subscribers, not viewers like these in my Youtube Studio view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, it just gets the general numbers without any customizations in the part 'statistics'

Answer (score 0):

You can get the demographics of subscribers by setting the following parameters of the report query for the YouTube Analytics API:

ids: channel==CHANNEL_ID
dimensions: ageGroup,gender,subscribedStatus
metrics: viewerPercentage
filters: subscribedStatus==SUBSCRIBED

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#demographic-reports

Comment: Tried this, however, subscribedStatus is always UNKNOWN in all my attempts